# Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:

Tags: xml, android-studio

I had designed GridLayout forgot to add `cardView` in `gradle`.

Later I added this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

to

```
build.gradle(module:app)
```

then clicked on

`Sync Now`

After this i got error in `gridLayout` of my code
i clicked on first option of fixing it...
i was unable to undo that, also i had 2 `xml` `content_main` and `content_main(v14)`

and below are the errors which were poped

> C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\ShoppingApp\app\src\main\res\layout\app_bar_main.xmlError:error: resource layout/content_main (aka com.example.shoppingapp:layout/content_main) not found.
>   Error:resource layout/content_main (aka com.example.shoppingapp:layout/content_main) not found.
>   Error:failed linking file resources.
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Failed to execute aapt

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background=""
android:weightSum="10"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.shoppingapp.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#1A237E"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Online Shopping"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#00BCD4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <!-- Column 1-->

</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your `build.gradle` what is `targetSdkVersion` number ?

Comment: targetSdkVersion26